# Locate a td with a specific value using xpath

Tags: xpath

Consider the following html fragment:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td><td>1</td>
    <td>Two</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use xpath to find the second td ("1" or "2") based on the value of the first td ("One" or "Two). Something like:

```
/table/tr/td[text() = 'One']/../td
```

or

```
/table/tr/td[text(), 'One']/../td
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`/table/tr/td[text()='One']/following-sibling::td[1]`

"The first `td` following-sibling of a `td` node with text `One`"

Answer (score 1):

following-sibling::td?

Comment: How do I specify limiting the path to the <td> who's value is "One"? It's not the sibling that's the issue; it's finding the td with a value of "One". Any chance you could give me an example of the entire xpath expression?

Comment: see AakashM's response. Although I don't think you need to specify the position in this case.  And if you decide to, I'd use position() and not [].